# What article would be correct here? A belief that / The belief that

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Can I change the definite article in the following sentence and remain grammatical?

> Once you adopt **the** **belief** that there's nothing you can do to change
>   something, you start to take a pernicious poison into your system.

I might mean that of all the beliefs someone might adopt you adopt one of them.
On this assumption, I might say ''**There's a belief that there's nothing you can do etc.**''
On the other hand, there might be only one belief that there's nothing you can do: **the belief**. If I can, what's the principle by which a native speaker chooses between the two? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Once you adopt **the belief** that there's nothing you can...*

... is absolutely correct because you are specific about *that* belief. And, that is why it'd take *the.*

Again, you are right! Now, you are introducing that belief and that's why you can put an indefinite article. It's the same as you say - there's ***a*** place called *Times Square.* There is *the* belief somehow does not look idiomatic, at least to me.

Comment: Can I replace the definite article in the first example? I've found some examples so it seems to be fine. ''Some people back up a belief that life is not worth living.''

Comment: Yes, because you are introducing it... by naming it. I already said that in the answer.

Comment: ''With the beliefs young Talmadge expressed so beautifully, I guarantee that he will have **a great opportunity** to continuously interpret their lives in **a way** that will create the future they desire, rather than the one that most people fear.'' Can we also change the articles above to the definite ones? A great opportunity means I'm introducing it, but I also can be specifit about this opportunity, can't I?